# Inserting a serial type field data in postgresql using java

Tags: java, postgresql, insert

This is my code which is not working

```
    String sql="insert into user_master(User_Id,'First_Name','Last_Name','Address','City','Country','Email_Id',Cell_Number) values(DEFAULT,'"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+country+"','"+email+"',"+cellno+")";
```

This one is working fine

```
    String sql="insert into user_master values(1,'"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+country+"','"+email+"',"+cellno+")";
```

But I don't want to increment id every time, I have already used serial type as i specified. But with DEFAULT it's not working.

Any idea?

Comment: You should really be using a prepared statement.

Comment: With that it will be working fine?

Comment: No, I just meant that without it your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ya. Thanks @David Conrad. Any idea where am lacking in the code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with postgresql. What happens if you simply omit all reference to the User_Id column? I'm guessing it's the primary key; is it set up to autoincrement?

Comment: Yes it is primary key, serial datatype does the work of auto increment. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named columns, and omit the one you want to have defaulted:

```
String sql="insert into user_master(first_name,last_name,address,city,country,email_id,cell_number) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+country+"','"+email+"',"+cellno+")";
```

This will solve your problem, but you should still use a prepared statement as mentioned above for other reasons (SQL injection, quoting issues, etc).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still its not working. With error                 ERROR: syntax error at or near "'First_Name'"

Comment: Now following error appear ERROR: column "first_name" of relation "user_master" does not exist. Even though Column First_Name is there in table user_master.

Comment: This might be due to the way you created your table if you quoted your columns when you created the table, the case might be different.  Verify how it looks in the database, and try using double quotes around the column names:  "First_Name","Last_Name". Also make sure to escape the double quotes in Java.

Comment: No they are the same. But i fixed the problem by converting all the fields to lower case. May be that means postgresql support lower case fields names.

Comment: Did you convert the fields in your java code or in the database table?  By default postgresql field names are not case sensitive, but if you declare them inside double quotes, they will be case sensitive.